# Trac project link hangs indefinitely over SSL

Tags: ssl, apache2, trac

I set up Trac with mod_wsgi, and all seems well except I can't access the projects. I can successfully see the list of projects after I log in, but Trac will hang indefinitely if I try to click on any of the projects.

If I run the same apache setup over port 80, everything runs fine. However I do not want it over port 80. I also generated my own certificates, which I am using. I can't spot what's wrong with my setup?

Here are the general steps I took:

```
cd /etc/apache2/sites-available
vi default-ssl
a2ensite default-ssl
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Going to `https://www.myserver.com/trac` shows my list of trac projects.
Clicking on any of these results in trac hanging. ie, `https://www.myserver.com/trac/project1` hangs.

sites-available/default-ssl:

```
    <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        # Trac settings
        WSGIScriptAlias /trac /var/lib/trac/apache/trac.wsgi
        <Directory /var/lib/trac/apache>
                WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
                 Order deny,allow
                 Allow from all
        </Directory>

        # Trac authentication stuff
        <Location /trac>
                AuthName "Trac login"
                AuthType Basic
                AuthUserFile /var/lib/trac/.htpasswd
                require valid-user
        </Location>

        # Trac mod_rewrite rules
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
                RewriteEngine On
                RewriteLog "/var/lib/trac/logs/rewrite.log"
                RewriteLogLevel 9

                # Don't let DirectoryIndex mess with Trac installed in the root
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
                RewriteRule . /trac [QSA,PT,L]

                # Don't let Trac handle existing directories, files or aliases
                RewriteCond /var/lib/trac%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
                RewriteCond /var/lib/trac%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
                # prepend /trac to URI and append Query String, Pass-Through to xxxAlias  directives, Last rule.
                RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /trac$1 [QSA,PT,L]
        </IfModule>

        ....

      </VirtualHost>
      </IfModule>
```

Testing trac with http works just fine:

httpd.conf:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /trac /var/lib/trac/apache/trac.wsgi

<Directory /var/lib/trac/apache>
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<Location /trac>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Trac login"
    AuthUserFile /var/lib/trac/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
</Location>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know, this is really odd. I decided I'd reload the page. This time, I got the standard unverified certificate question, which I accepted...

Now trac has loaded completely. So it's fine now.

I had thought I already accepted the certificate before though. This is very odd!